# Iterating over the colums of a dataframe without using for loop in r

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vectorization

Below are the train and test sets, `train_dat` and `test_dat` respectively. I want to iterate through each categorical column in the dataframes and assign each level to an integer that is determined by alphabetical order of the levels of the categorical variable. The integer values to assigned are stored in `uniqueValuesTrain`. Without using for loop, how can I achieve a faster and vectorized solution?

```r
# Data 

cat_var_1 <- c("blue", "green", "green", "blue", "red", "brown")
cat_var_2 <- c("rock", "blues", "jazz", "jazz", "rock", "indie")
reg_var_1 <- c(23, 22, 21, 24, 56, 28)
target <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)

train_dat <- data.frame(cat_var_1, cat_var_2, reg_var_1 , target, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)


cat_var_1 <- c("green", "green", "blue", "blue", "green", "purple", "magenta")
cat_var_2 <- c("rock", "rock", "jazz", "jazz", "jazz", "pop", "house")
reg_var_1 <- c(12, 23, 25, 27, 34, 12, 32)
target <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0)

test_dat <- data.frame(cat_var_1, cat_var_2, reg_var_1 ,target, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

targetVariable <- "target"
catVariables <- names(Filter(is.factor, train_dat))

# Remove target variable from catVariables
catVariables <- catVariables[!(catVariables %in% targetVariable)]

# Integer Encoding

trainInt <- copy(train_dat)
testInt <- copy(test_dat)

for(col in catVariables){
  uniqueValuesTrain <- sort(unique(trainInt[[col]]))
  trainInt[[col]] <- match(trainInt[[col]], uniqueValuesTrain)
  testInt[[col]] <- match(testInt[[col]], uniqueValuesTrain)
}
```

Comment: Not clear about what you wanted?  Do you need a tidyverse solution i.e. `train_dat %>% mutate(across(all_of(catVariables), ~ match(.x, sort(unique(.x)))));test_dat %>% mutate(across(all_of(catVariables), ~ match(.x, sort(unique(train_dat[[cur_column()]])))))`   `match` is a vectorized function and it is looping over the columns which is essentially the same in `across`

Comment: @akrun this would work but can you post it as an answer? I tried it and it does not work yet

Comment: For me it is working.  I am using `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.8’`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
train_dat <- train_dat %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(catVariables),
     ~ match(.x, sort(unique(.x))),
    .names = "{.col}_new"))
test_dat <- test_dat %>% 
   mutate(across(all_of(catVariables), 
   ~ match(.x, sort(unique(train_dat[[cur_column()]]))), .names = "{.col}_new"))
```

-output

```
> train_dat
  cat_var_1 cat_var_2 reg_var_1 target cat_var_1_new cat_var_2_new
1      blue      rock        23      1             1             4
2     green     blues        22      0             3             1
3     green      jazz        21      1             3             3
4      blue      jazz        24      0             1             3
5       red      rock        56      0             4             4
6     brown     indie        28      1             2             2
> test_dat
  cat_var_1 cat_var_2 reg_var_1 target cat_var_1_new cat_var_2_new
1     green      rock        12      1             3             4
2     green      rock        23      1             3             4
3      blue      jazz        25      1             1             3
4      blue      jazz        27      0             1             3
5     green      jazz        34      1             3             3
6    purple       pop        12      0            NA            NA
7   magenta     house        32      0            NA            NA
```

Comment: still this solution returns the same dataframe for me and does not change anything :( might be related to dplyr version. Also can I not include the categorical columns in the output

Comment: @moli your comment is not clear as I created two new columns with `_new`.  can you show your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: I made it work on another version of r, thank you. My question was if we can remove the categorical variables that are not transformed and only keep the ones with "_new"

Comment: @moli if you need only those _new, then use `transmute` instead of `mutate` i.e. `train_dat %>%
  transmute(across(all_of(catVariables),
     ~ match(.x, sort(unique(.x))),
    .names = "{.col}_new"))`

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler:

```
library(data.table)
f <- function(x) match(x,sort(unique(x)))
setDT(train_dat)[,(catVariables):=lapply(.SD,f),.SDcols = catVariables][]
setDT(test_dat)[,(catVariables):=lapply(.SD,f),.SDcols = catVariables][]
```

Output:

```
   cat_var_1 cat_var_2 reg_var_1 target
       <int>     <int>     <num>  <num>
1:         1         4        23      1
2:         3         1        22      0
3:         3         3        21      1
4:         1         3        24      0
5:         4         4        56      0
6:         2         2        28      1

  cat_var_1 cat_var_2 reg_var_1 target
       <int>     <int>     <num>  <num>
1:         2         4        12      1
2:         2         4        23      1
3:         1         2        25      1
4:         1         2        27      0
5:         2         2        34      1
6:         4         3        12      0
7:         3         1        32      0
```